# Display different ArrayLists in each tab

Tags: java, android, arrays, tabs, android-tabs

I am trying to figure out how to display two different array lists one in each tab cause at the moment both my planets and stars array lists and showing up under all my tabs.

I did get it right to where if I create an activity + class for each tab but that is way too many tabs to create an activity + class for each one

How can I display each in a different tab like under the planets tab is the planets array list and under stars tab is the stars array list but just reuse the same activity for all tabs but just populate new text data for each tab

Here is my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private ViewPager mPager;
private SlidingTabLayout mTabs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    mTabs=(SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    mTabs.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    mTabs.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    String[] tabs;



    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        tabs=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        MyFragment myFragment=MyFragment.getInstance(position);
        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
}

public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView textView;
    private ListView mainListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;

    public static MyFragment getInstance(int position){

        MyFragment myFragment=new MyFragment();
        Bundle  args=new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        myFragment.setArguments(args);
        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);

        mainListView=(ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.mainListView);

        String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",
                "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};
        ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
        planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );

        String[] stars = new String[] { "Eridanus", "Cassiopeia", "Scorpius", "Crux",
                "Cancer", "Leo", "Canis Major", "Taurus"};
        ArrayList<String> starsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(stars) );

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.simplerow, planetList);
        mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
        return layout;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch case on the basis of pagerposition like

```
ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();

switsh(pagerposition){

Case 0:
     String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",
                "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};
        planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );
    break;

Case 1: 

       String[] stars = new String[] { "Eridanus", "Cassiopeia", "Scorpius",   "Crux", "Cancer", "Leo", "Canis Major", "Taurus"};
        planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(stars) );
break;

and so on.....
}
```

Comment: This gives me errors when trying to implement in onViewCreate im still noob with Java I need little more info like where to implement and the pagerpostion must I make a new var called pagerpostion cause I cant switch "position"